# Shouldn't I do standardization when data is not normally distributed?

Tags: machine-learning, normalization, standardization, computational-statistics

I am trying to scale the data prior to clustering analysis, and got a question.
The goal of scaling at this point is to unify(eliminate) the unit of all input variables so that make influence of each variable to results same.
Thus, I guess I have to apply same scaling measure to all variables, and I am considering between standardization and normalization. Observations are 600, and distributions of 4 input variables are like followings[image][enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7bgVp.png)[image][image][image]

As I know standardization only can be applied when the data is normally distributed. So at this point, is it right choosing minmax normalization as scaling measure?

Comment: Standardization can be done on any variable, regardless of its distribution. The result very likely won't be normal in this case, but that is not necessary.

Comment: @user2974951 Yeah...scaled result is very one-sided of course. But then isn't there any disadvantege or problem that comes after the standardization of non-normally distributed data, instead of normalization?

Comment: Normalization means different things across statistical science. Without knowing the precise recipe you used it is hard to answer your question. For example, I have seen it used to mean something like (value - max) / (max - min) and also to mean some kind of transformation to bring values closer to a normal distribution. If there are yet other meanings, that strengthens my point. On the other hand, standardization meaning (value - mean) / SD is really nothing do with normal distributions and can be applied anywhere so long as mean and SD  make sense as summaries and SD is positive.

Comment: Note that some kind of bimodality (e.g.) is entirely good news for clustering as if your data were multivariate normal there would be little or no point in clustering.

Comment: Standardization necessarily will not change the shape of a distribution, so the result is exactly as non-normal as the input. If texts or courses imply or state otherwise, run in the opposite direction, as the explanation is utterly incorrect on an elementary point that is essentially high (secondary) school mathematics. .